# Restoring deleted AD object

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, restore

I have a Windows 2003 domain and Windows 2003 domain controller.

I accidentally deleted the whole container.  The container contains some child `container` objects `group` object and some `serviceConnectionPoint` object.  I am looking for a way to undelete it.

I come across this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379542(WS.10).aspx), which seems to imply that it's possible to restore a just-deleted AD object by reanimating the tombstone object.

I googled a bit and found [ADRestore](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963906).  I  tried it and it could successfully restore my child `container` objects and `group` object but not the `serviceConnectionPoint` objects.  It looks like it cannot even find any tombstone objects with the objectClass `serviceConnectionPoint`.  Is it a limitation of the tool or is it a limitation in AD?  Is there any other commercial tools that can help restoring the deleted AD object reliably?

Comment: What are you using for backups? In the future, I recommend Backup Exec with the AD recovery agent.

Comment: The Active Directory recycle bin is new to Windows Server 2008 R2 and your domain functional level must be 2008 R2, so unfortunately that's not going to fly for you. Also, tombstone re-animation was never that great anyway as not all attributes were recovered. To answer your immediate question: **the best tool to restore a deleted Active Directory object is a system state backup**. If you have no backups of such a critical piece of infrastructure such as Active Directory, I'm afraid I have no sympathy.

Comment: I only have VM snapshot, which I think it's a bad idea to be used for restoring AD.  What kind of backup tools do you recommend?

Comment: If you don't want to shell out for a commercial backup utility, Windows comes with a perfectly functional one baked in.

Comment: Not that functional. There are lots of things it does not do well.

Comment: Fair enough, but it does do what it says on the tin and will produce a consistent Active Directory backup. If you want the granularity or extra features then you go and buy the commercial software with the bells and whistles that you want. It's all about the trade-off you want to make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put one of your DCs in recovery mode and restore from backup.

As @Holocryptic pointed out, here's the link to that: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779573(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Link:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779573(WS.10).aspx